# Unable to bind json string to object in controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a Spring MVC application and sending Ajax call on click of a submit Button.

Below is the Controller Method:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addTask" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addTask(@ModelAttribute(value="task") Task task, BindingResult result, Model model){
        String returnText = null;
        System.out.println(task.getDescription()); // printing null
        return "success" ;
    }
```

But I am getting all the attributes in `Task` object as **null** .

However I am able to receive json as String in the controller and convert to Object via Gson api.

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addTask" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addTask(@RequestBody String task){
        String returnText = null;

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Task rr = gson.fromJson(task, Task.class);
        taskList.add(rr);
        return "success" ;
    }
```

Below is the ajax code:

```
 function doAjaxPost() {

        var id = $('#id').val();
        var desc = $('#description').val();
        var dueDate = $('#dueDate').val();
        var obj = { "id" : id, "description" : desc, "dueDate": dueDate};
        console.log(obj)

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "/spring/addTask",
            data : JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType : 'json',
            timeout : 100000,

            success: function(response){
            $('#description').val('');
            $('#dueDate').val('');
            $('#id').val('');
            },
            error: function(e){
            alert('Error: ' + e);
            console.log(e);
            }
            });
            }
```

I have already added the below 2 dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why JSON was not able to Bind to the object as I was not `implement Serializable` in my POJPO class.

After I implemented `Serializable`, the problem is solved.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `contentType : "application/json"` from your Ajax call while making the POST request . It will set the values in model and 100% work . Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var str = $("#myForm").serialize();`if you are creating your model attribute with form. otherwise, send straightforward `obj.serialize()` in ajax's data part.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add consumes={"application/json"} to your @RequestMapping annotation. Automatic conversion then should be performed provided jackson dependencies are on the classpath. You should not need @ModelAttribute annotation anymore after that.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/addTask" , method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
public String addTask(Task task, BindingResult result, Model model){
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is not solving my problem. Do you mind If I give you a small zipped project having my code? I will be reallly greatful to you